# REST API for streams redeployment

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to redeploy streams using the REST API? The current documentation does not provide much info - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-stream-deployments

I am guessing one would need to execute this as a 2-step process (assuming there are REST APIs)

1. invoke un-deploy, followed by
2. deploy

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. We do not have a re-deployment workflow in SCDF. You will have to do that in 2 steps or you can operate on individual applications through the runtime-platform (e.g., cf or k8s) specific blue-green deployment options. Any external operations will eventually reflect the current state in SCDF streams.

All that said, you may want to look into [Skipper](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/) + SCDF integration. This is purpose-built to open-up CI/CD operations natively from within SCDF. The first milestone of skipper + scdf integration will be released this week. Here's an example of the UX in [CF](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/pull/368) and [K8S](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/pull/239).

The `stream skipper update ..` operation is backed by a REST endpoint and that can be used standalone, too.